# Water Heater Help

Tags: plumbing, water, heater, corrosion

I was woken to a pop and a electrical burning smell. Upon inspection I found the water heater breaker tripped. When I checked out the water heater I found whats pictured.
My question is the cold water line is coverd in corrosion and its leaking at the connector, what would cause this?[image]
And im checking on the warranty since it was installed about 2 years ago. But if that corrosion is in the line is the tank full of it?
[image]

Comment: Do you have an unvented cloths dryer in this area?

Comment: That does not look like corrosion ... I do not think that plastic pipes corrode. Have you tried to wipe it off?

Comment: Is there anything done right in that photo? Are you trolling us?

Comment: Yep, I agree with JACK, Dryer lint sticking to condensation on the cold water pipe.

Comment: What make and model is the heater, and can you get a spare wiring cover for it? That sounds like a bigger problem than the leak, even...

Comment: Also, can you try taking some bits of that stuff off the pipe and seeing what its consistency is?

Answer (score -1):

I would be more worried about the electrical being not done to code. How can I say this Romex not protected?  With the leaks there could have been an electrical short. I do see a ball valve shutoff down a ways on the left side of the photo. Plastic doesn’t corrode but if not correctly glued it can drip causing the leaks , I haven’t seen pink pipe tape but it looks like that was used on the threaded fittings most primers have a blue or purple tint , then the glue don’t think I have seen your color glue especially in the last 5+ years  and last is that CPVC required for hot water for decades on the west coast not sure about every where else but for a 2 year old install it should be cpvc looks to have many violations both electrical and plumbing, on top of the leaks that caused the rust and scale on the pipes and water heater.

Comment: I tried to edit your answer to clean up this wall of text but had to cancel the effort. The total number of run together subjects included in the answer make things very confusing to decide what is relevant to the original question and what is not.

Comment: No kidding Ed Beal. That is a poster for code violations all around. But by the way, pink is the new color for Teflon tape when used on NPT threads over 3/8". Ugly if you ask me, but that's the new norm...

Comment: Is pink tape a different thickness? I went into my plumbing and electrical supply store and all they have is white. But they have 2 thickness. I guess that would make sense but I did not get the memo.